# Using TypeScript with Firebase - Cannot find module 'firebase/app'

Tags: typescript, firebase, node-modules

I'm trying to start a TypeScript project using Firebase, but I am not able to get TypeScript to like `import firebase from 'firebase/app';` It gives me the error `Cannot find module 'firebase/app'`.

But, I know for a fact that it works because I am able to console firebase - Typescript just doesn't like it. Is there anything special I have to do? I've seen some people say you have to install @types/firebase, but it says it's deprecated.

Edit:

tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "watch": true,
        "lib": [
            "DOM",
            "esnext"
        ],
        "moduleResolution": "node", // Tell tsc to look in node_modules for modules
        "strict": true,             // Strict types, eg. prohibits `var x=0; x=null`
        "alwaysStrict": true,        // Enable JavaScript's "use strict" mode
        "outDir": "./public"
    },
    "include": [
        "**/*.ts",
        "**/*.tsx"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

I solved the above issue by adding `"moduleResolution": "node"`. But, now when I add the script like so: `<script type="module" src="/index.js"></script>` where it's just `import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';` inside index.js - I get a browser error of: `TypeError: Module specifier does not start with "/", "./", or "../".` - testing on Safari 13.1.

Is there a different way to solve this? Typescript, Firebase all at latest version.

Comment: `@types/firebase` is deprecated because `firebase` ships its own types officially. Something is wrong with your setup. Provide more information: firebase package version, typescript version, tsconfig.json.

Answer (score 0):

Node resolution requires you to begin the path with the current dir:

```
import * as firebase from './firebase/app'
```

Comment: When I do this it says it cannot find the module. Maybe it's the way I install Firebase? Should it be in node_modules or is there a different way to build it? Also, I don't use Webpack or any other module framework; is it not possible without one of those?